# Is it better to pass reference to an object or pass individual attributes in an object in Java?

Tags: java, parameters

I'm dealing with legacy code and I constantly see method calls with multiple attributes from the same object being passed into a method:

```
update(user.getID(), user.getLanguage() etc...)
```

Is there a distinct advantage or disadvantage to doing it this way or would I just be as well to pass in the user object (in this case) and deal with attributes within the method called?

**Follow Up:**

Lots of excellent answers, thank you.  Apologies for the lack of exact detail in the question but as I said this is seen all over the system I am working on and this seemed like a nice simple example.  Please feel free to turn this question into a community wiki question as no one answer can possibly be accepted over others as they're all good and have valid points.

Comment: In multithreaded environment it can be dangerous to pass to the whole value object. But it is up to you to decide.

Comment: I'd say that in such case your method becomes more reusable since it only operates on basic data types and not on some `User` object.

Comment: @Andrew Logvinov: the whole damn point of OO is to encapsulate data in objects.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt I thik that this question is too loosely specified to make that judgement. If it is only supposed to operate on user obejcts then yes, pass the user object. If not, pass the more basic types.

Comment: Lots of valid answers here which is excellent.  In this case the class containing update is massive (16,000+ lines (urgh!)) and contains reference to User in it.  And so I'll look at passing the object in but once I refactor everything back (probably in a million years) I'll consider decoupling and moving the object out if it proves a better solution :)

Answer (score 16):

Both have their advantages. I'd decide for each method depending on what it is supposed to do. For legacy code, though, I'd prefer to not change anything unless there is actually a problem.

Pro several values, con object reference:

- you're not bound to a specific class, you can pass values from other sources
- method cannot (unexpectedly) change object state (C++ could use "const" for this)

Pro passing a single user object:

- you're bound to user objects, making it difficult to accidentally pass unrelated / invalid values
- it's obvious that the method expects data of a user object
- changing (e.g. renaming) a getter requires changes at all invocations of the method and not just in its implementation
- similar if a new property is added and needs to be passed
- method can change object state

As you see a property can be considered an advantage or disadvantage depending on your needs.

Comment: Maybe this is a noob question, but: Could you have 2 update methods in the class, one that gets the separate parameters, and one that gets the object and internally separates the parameters and calls the other one? This way you could use it both ways depending on what parameters you are inputing.

Comment: @EKI  You can.  I've done it before where there's a very common, but not universal, source for the input; or when creating the object used in the common case had baggage I didn't want to deal with in some spots (expensive initialization, or would need to provide placeholder/dummy values to the constructor).

Comment: Almost worth a -1 because you say that passing values is even slightly acceptalbe.  In the first case you list it's a design problem (Should be using interfaces, therefore no restriction) in the second state-changes should be rare but when they are needed they shouldn't present a problem.  All I'm saying is that the string,string,string solution is just not knowing how to program OO, period.

Comment: @BillK I disagree with that as an absolute statement.  Loading a class down with 20 interfaces, each of which makes a single function call made one time prettier is a bigger mess than dumping the otherwise useless interfaces and using value passing in each case.

Comment: @Dan Neely that also sounds like a bad solution--if you have seen that, your classes are doing too much and need to be refactored down to a single purpose.  If your class only has a single responsibility it should only need one or two interfaces.  You can't just ignore a few OO design principles or EVERYTHING falls apart, follow them all and you end up with some great code generally.

Comment: @BillK Whether passing values is acceptable depends on the usecase and the intention of the method, IMHO. If the mentioned `update` method takes the data and updates the user entry in the database, passing in separate values is a bad idea. If the method is often called with information from a user object, but that is just a "coincidence" and not by design of the method I think it is not only acceptable but you'll unnecessarily lose the liberty to call it with data from different sources. Nothing speaks against an overloaded variant taking a whole user object as parameter, though. :)

Comment: @user1252434 Your example, a method called with related data by coincidence is exactly what I mean by something that sounds like bad code.  Why wouldn't you just design it better?  Identifying stuff like this is what can improve your code--which is really my point--It's not like really evil to do this, just always an indication that you should look for so that you can see the oppourtinity to make your code better

Comment: @BillK Basically my argument boils down to coupling. By "coincidence" I meant when `update` and `user` are not (by design, logic) coupled. E.g. `update` could atomically change the content of an UI element with several subelements (-> several parameters). That UI element could be used to show user data, or any other values. In that case coupling it (unnecessarily) to the `user` class would lose this freedom. It still looks bad if it is called this way again and again. Especially from outside its (e.g. UI) layer. A helper method or subclass with overloaded `update` method would be much nicer.

Comment: @user1252434 Yeah, I agree--the fail case for OO code is utilities such as gui controls, database objects or collections.  All those cases tend to lead to bad OO.  Generally I think that these things should be wrapped in a true object that is a better match for your domain.  For instance, you will save a lot of effort creating your own UI element that actually understands the relationship between update and user and takes those classes directly rather than accepting a bunch of arbitrary parameters to generic methods.

Answer (score 15):

In fact, it would be much, **much** better to pass a reference to the object, for two reasons:

- it avoids repetition of all the getters in every place the method is called (DRY principle)
- it leads to shorter method signatures. Methods should almost never have more than three parameters because it's too easy to get confused about the order, and hard to refactor.

To avoid excessively long parameter lists, the recommended refactoring is to create a object that contains all the data - aren't you lucky that you already have such an object?

Comment: Except if OP doesn't want to couple the callee to the object that he is decomposing in the args. He might for example call the same method by decomposing diverse objects. I wouldn't know how to advise given so little information.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: in that case the parameter type should be an interface containing the getters, which can then be implemented by different classes. "Decomposing" objects into a list of parameters for a method calls is a fundamentally wrong thing to do.

Comment: Exactly. In that case OP should introduce a new model object belonging to the called API (builder pattern preferred, or custom conversion constructors).

Answer (score 6):

It depends if you will accept dependency on the object class from the calling method.

When using this

```
update(user)
```

The class where update is declared must know about the class of user.

If you use this

```
update(user.getID(), user.getLanguage() etc...)
```

and the members are primitives or belongs to Java standard library than there is no further dependency in update() to class of user ...

Comment: Possible a good case for adding an extra level of abstraction in.  Thanks for your answer PeterMmm :)

Answer (score 6):

This is a kind of code smell that would make me consider moving the update() method to the user class. One of the Great Principles of Object Oriented Design is [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) - bundle your data, and operations on that data, together.

Then you have the [Tell, Don't Ask](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask) principle. It's better to tell an object to do something than to ask it for information.

> Procedural code gets information then makes decisions. Object-oriented code tells objects to do things.

Of course I don't have enough details to say you should definitely do such a thing, but it's something to consider.

Comment: I think this is one of the best answers here.  There is no question, passing the parameters individually is not only a bad smell, it's just plain wrong IF you own both objects.  The one case where this tends to happen is when you are using a pre-created library that only has the ability to take string, string, string--and even then I'd say it was a poorly designed library and you should create wrapper classes for most of it.

Comment: Agreed, this is a great answer, this is exactly how I would do this sort of thing nowadays, encapsulate the functionality of what to update in the User object (single responsibility), and pass the storage service or repository to the method if required.  It's been a long time since I asked this but in the case of this example I should have created a method in the User object: updateLanguage(repository), or whatever the distinct unit of functionality is e.g.: updateUserLocalePreferences(repository)

Answer (score 3):

1. It looks weird
2. It means that the method signature looks like `update(String, String, String...)` which introduces the risk to pass arguments in the wrong order
3. If you need to take a new attribute into account in your update method at some stage, you won't need to change the method's signature, only its implementation.
4. I don't know what `update` does, but it might make sense to make it part of the user class: `user.update(additionalInformation)`.

Answer (score 3):

For my experience I thought that it depends on what the method should do, if it is strict linked to the object that contains all the parameters it is better to pass the object, for example in a DAO object that does an update or a save it is better to pass the Domain object, otherwise if the method is more generic, and there is the possibility that all the parameters don't come from the same object is better to pass the parameters to the method.

Comment: Thank you rascio.  Yes I need to consider what the purpose of the update method is and what level of abstraction is needed.  For now I think I'll be fine to pass in the user object as the User is highly generic but I want to tidy up the code and pull these heavy references out by making them more specific so I'll move to passing individual parameters once I have the system in a clean state (it will take a long time lol) :)

Answer (score 2):

It's a little hard to say what it is your method updates from your code snippet. But if you pass in the user object, you will have coupeled the user object to the method. If you just pass in strings, ints etc, you can use the method with sources other than user. My advice is that you should not force the method to be more specific than it needs to be.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that you're dealing with legacy code you need to be sure that changing a method

signature does not break any code that may be calling it. If you have complete control over the code base that would call these methods, then yes you can simplify the code by just passing in the `user` object.

You should also consider whether the user object a "heavy weight" object that loads additional data that could be wasteful to create, each time you call these methods. This would be one reason why you may not pass the `user` object as a parameter. The same reasonin applies to lazy-loaded objects.

The other possible reason for not passing the entire object through could be that you dont want it to be updated by the method and for "some reason" cannot be made to be immutable. The getter methods for the user objects' can be made to return "safe defensive copies" of the values. See Joshua Bloch's effective java for this type of coding practise especially useful in multi thread applications.

Comment: I've read that article on how to make immutable objects by Joshua (he's very clever).  But yes I do need to consider the size of User (in this case).  Thank you for your answer Brad :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no advantage in passing properties of *one* object as separate arguments to a method.  The disadvantage of it is that the code becomes hard to read and maintain. The lesser arguments, the better. If You can combine the arguments in one object, just do it.

There is a refactoring technique, in case You want to refactor that, called [Preserve Whole Object](http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/catalog/preserveWholeObject.html). You might also find my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10489252/1333481) on the similar subject to be useful.

Comment: Thank you for the link to your other answer.  Very useful :)